# How to keep an element in list depending on condition in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, loops

I would like something that looks like this :

```
for elements in ref_series_list:
    z = 100
    if len(ref_series_list)>=1:       
       if z_voxel_size in Series_table.at[elements, 'z_voxel_size']<z:
           z_min = z_voxel_size         
  
           df1.at[elements, 'ref_series_id'] = df2.ID[elements][z_voxel_size]
```

The part `if z_voxel_size in Series_table.at[elements, 'z_voxel_size'] < z` doesn't work because it says `'Numpy.float64' object is not iterable.`

The `elements` in list represent ID that are in `df2` and I would like to keep the element that has the lowest `z_voxel_size` in the `df2` corresponding to the ID.

My list is [8,9]. The 8 correspond to the ID 8 in column ID in df2 and has a z_voxel_size of 1.25 in the column z_voxel_size of df2 and the 9 correspond to the ID 9 in column ID in df2 and has a z_voxel_size of 0.625 in the column z_voxel_size of df2. So I would like that my list contains only 9 and not 8 and after store this 9 in a new dataframe df1.

Comment: Use [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to create a [mre] that simplifies your problem and lets us execute the code to see somehting. Currently your code is out of context and not runnable.

Comment: First you may want to check [pandas-groupby-and-select-rows-with-the-minimum-value-in-a-specific-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470917/pandas-groupby-and-select-rows-with-the-minimum-value-in-a-specific-column) and see if that helps you . Grouping by ID and then keeping min might just be what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Sorry I'm new here and I didn't want to put all my code to show the data frames because it's very long. I tried to explain more what's in the list, hopefully it will help you ! Thank you for the link, it shows how to do it in a DataFrame and not in a list so I didn't find a solution for now