# pandas groupby ID and select row with minimal value of specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

i want to select the whole row in which the minimal value of 3 selected columns is found, in a dataframe like this:

[image]

it is supposed to look like this afterwards:

[image]

I tried something like

```
dfcheckminrow = dfquery[dfquery == dfquery['A':'C'].min().groupby('ID')]
```

obviously it didn't work out well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the column A nominates 2 minimum values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas GroupBy and select rows with the minimum value in a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470917/pandas-groupby-and-select-rows-with-the-minimum-value-in-a-specific-column)

Comment: There are two min values from A because there are different ID groups. @Jyr it is the direction i want, but I need to check the min over multiple columns not just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bkeesey's answer looks like it almost got you to your solution. I added one more step to get the overall minimum for each group.

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
               'A': [30, 14, 100, 67, 1, 20], 
               'B': [10, 1, 2, 5, 100, 3],
               'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
               })

# set "ID" as the index
df = df.set_index('ID')

# get the min for each column
mindf = df[['A','B']].groupby('ID').transform('min')

# get the min between columns and add it to df
df['min'] = mindf.apply(min, axis=1)

# filter df for when A or B matches the min
df2 = df.loc[(df['A'] == df['min']) | (df['B'] == df['min'])]

print(df2)
```

In my simplified example, I'm just finding the minimum between columns A and B. Here's the output:

```
      A    B  C  min
ID
1    14    1  2    1
2   100    2  3    2
3     1  100  5    1
```

Answer (score 0):

One method do filter the initial DataFrame based on a groupby conditional could be to use `transform` to find the minimum for a "ID" group and then use `loc` to filter the initial DataFrame where `any(axis=1) (checking rows) is met.

```
# create sample df
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], 
               'A': [30, 14, 100, 67, 1, 20], 
               'B': [10, 1, 2, 5, 100, 3]})
# set "ID" as the index
df = df.set_index('ID')
```

Sample df:

```
      A    B
ID          
1    30   10
1    14    1
2   100    2
2    67    5
3     1  100
3    20    3
```

Use groupby and transform to find minimum value based on "ID" group.
Then use `loc` to filter initial df to where `any(axis=1)` is valid

```
df.loc[(df == df.groupby('ID').transform('min')).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
      A    B
ID          
1    14    1
2   100    2
2    67    5
3     1  100
3    20    3
```

In this example only the first row should be removed as it in both columns is not a minimum for the "ID" group.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, next time i will stick to it. My Problem with your answer is that it combines the min() values of each row of one group. I wanted to pick out the min() value and output the original row of one group which includes the min().

Comment: Ah ok I think I understand. You want to use the minimum of each grouped ID as a conditional to filter the original DataFrame? Is that correct?

Comment: yes, that is my intention.

Comment: @k1k0 I made an edit to my answer. I am not sure if it is the best way to do it as the  `transform` and then equality check is likely not the most efficient way to find the correct indexers for `loc`